# Conan auto increment packet version

Tags: version, conan

I started using Conan to handle my C++ code base and I do not understand if it offers a way to automatically increment a package version after uploading a release.

I am talking about something like **npm postpublish hook script** that I use to execute `npm version patch`: so I am always sure that after a release, I am working on a new version.

I there any command that updates version field inside my `conanfile.py`? Is it automatically callable after a deploy?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no auto-incrementing feature for conan. The main reason is that it is not clear that a `conan upload` necessarily means bumping the version. For example, you might run a `conan create` to create a x86 binary, then upload it. After that, you create a package binary, exactly with the same recipe and version, for 64bits, x86_64, and upload it.

You don't want to bump to a different version. So bumping the version is done explicitly in the recipe `version` field. It can also be skipped in the recipe, and just defined in the command line: `conan create . pkg/version@user/channel`, but it is up to the user to define the version.

A different feature would be the package "revisions". Those will assign a new, transparent revision for each recipe change or binary rebuild. It is an ongoing work, so it might take some time until it is there.